# Clean install cinnamon

Tags: desktop-environments, cinnamon

I installed cinnamon a while ago and didn't like it so I removed it (followed some post online to remove it completely as `apt-get autoremove cinnamon` wasn't very successful).

After removing it, I was still left with `gnome` and `gnome 2D`

Today I reinstalled it (`apt-get install cinnamon`) and I logged in using cinnamon and as son as I so much as pressed a key or clicked an icon, it crashed. I had to shut down using a virtual console.

How can I fix this? I would prefer removing Cinnamon + Gnome + Gnome 2D completely and installing cinnamon again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
```

This should completely remove it along with any configuration files that might be causing issues.